# 404.17 - Unable to serve any aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am unable to get my website loaded in-browser after deploying it to our server.

The specific error I'm getting is:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found The requested content appears to be
>   script and will not be served by the static file handler.

I've checked out a few other questions talking about this error and have done some research online as well.

- I can verify that ASP.NET is installed (both 3.5 and 4.5).
- I can verify that .aspx is found in the handlers for the site.
- The site is running in a .NET v4.0 Application Pool
- I've run the aspnet_regiis.exe -i executable from the command line in the appropriate folder.
- I am running IIS 8.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Let me know if I can provide any further detail.

Comment: Check that permissions for the web site allow running scripts.

Comment: Andrei, thanks for the comment - I must be blind; where is the option to add that permission?

Comment: Handler Mappings -> Edit feature permissions. Make sure both Read and Script are checked

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes - both are checked. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Server 2012, there's two different places to look to see if ASP.NET is installed.

( I was not checking both... )

See below:

[image: First place to check]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem lots of time . just go to IIS -> select your website -> go to handler mapping and then press revert to parent option . it will solve your problem i think .